# Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Tags: database, web-config, iis-7.5, ssms

Hi i get the following error message when trying to connect to DB in sql server management studio 2008

```
07/23/2014 09:52:14,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'usernamehere'. Reason: Failed to      open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
07/23/2014 09:52:14,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456<c/> Severity: 14<c/> State: 38.
```

Running IIS 7.5 App Pool 4.0

Ive created a user mapped it to the database selected dboOwner yet it still doesn't connect. I've also set the database option "Auto Close" to false. It was set to true before. The same username and password allows me to connect to the database through Management Studio 2008.

```
Line 2:      if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
Line 3:      {
Line 4:          WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Users",
Line 5:  
Line 6:  "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

Source File: e:\AdminPanel\_AppStart.cshtml    Line: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your connection string?  It should be something like:

```
server=<my database server>;database=<my database>;trusted_connection=false;User Id=<user you have created in sql server management studio>;Password=<my password>
```

Of course, do not actually include the angle brackets in the string.

In my case, I needed in SQL Server Management Studio to open Security on the entire Server (not just on the database) and ensure that the user mapping was set to map database to my SQL user.

Here are a couple websites you may find useful:

https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2581/sql-server-error-18456-finding-the-missing-databases/

Otherwise, please provide more details to troubleshoot.